# How to save QPainter instance

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application where I use `QPainter` to draw on a `QPixmap` which is then through `QLabel` displayed on the screen. Mainly it's drawing text and it's doing it several times every second.

I see it inefficient when the `QPainter` instance is constructing several times per second (including it's settings like font, pen etc.). So my question is, how can I save the instance of `QPainter` and reuse it later? I've tried this but it doesn't preserve the "settings" of the `QPainter`:

```
this->painter = new QPainter(&this->canvas); // this->cavas is a QPixmap
painter->setFont(this->font);
painter->setPen(this->font_color);

//...

painter->begin(&this->canvas);
painter->drawText(0, 0, 20, 20, "test");
painter->end();
```

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot save QPainter in between paint calls. You could cache its settings though (e.g. font, pen, etc.).

Comment: @hauron Why? How do I cache its settings?

Comment: Do you really have problems with speed or is this premature optimization?

Comment: Have to agree with @Mailerdaimon.  I've got lots of code that updates visually at 60Hz or so and having to set up the `QPainter` on each update has *never* been an issue.  Your case may be different of course but unless you can give more details about what work is being done on each update cycle it's difficult to tell.

Comment: No, I don't have problems with speed yet. I'm just starting the project and I just want it to be fast. Alright, I'll set up the QPainter on every update. Thanks for advices

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I understood it was due to QPainter being in fact a tiny little layer on top of low-level paint. See docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html. I was speaking partly from experience, as I tried to cache it too, failing. If you really cared, you could go as far as to check the implementation (it should quickly drop to low-level stuff, e.g. native draw calls) or just debug the internal pointers QPainter stores (QPaintDevice, QPaintEngine). I'd suspect these change on every call.